# Read a PKCS12 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, openssl, p12

I tried running this code to parse a PKCS12 but for some reason, It didn't run and it gave me this error.

Does any one know a fix to this?

The Error:

```
main.rb:4:in `initialize': PKCS12_parse: mac verify failure (OpenSSL::PKCS12::PKCS12Error)
        from main.rb:4:in `new'
        from main.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

The code:

```
require 'openssl'


  pkcs12 = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(File.read("cert.p12"), "AppleP12.com")

  puts pkcs12.key
```

Comment: `File.read` defaults to UTF-8. Try [`File.binread`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/IO.html#method-c-binread) to get binary data. Otherwise, the password could be wrong.

Comment: @Stefan I just checked that the password matches it, and binread doesnt work!

Comment: Can you verify this is a PKCS12 file with another tool, e.g. `openssl`?

Comment: Yes I can with bash! @tadman

Comment: `bash` alone can't do it, but another tool could. Which one?